# GADTs, unparametrized types and instance Eq for them

Tags: haskell, gadt, existential-type

I have a container type, called `X`. Since I want heterogeneous lists over `X`, its constructor is existentially typed over some type variable `a`. However, I want it to be an instance of the `Eq` type class. A hackish solution looks like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data X where X :: (Eq a, Show a) => a -> X

instance Eq X where
    X x == X y = show x == show y
```

What would be the simplest (clean) solution for this problem?

(`X`s don't equal if they don't have the same type.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `Typeable` so that you have a runtime representation of the type; then use `cast` to cast one of them to the appropriate type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
import Data.Typeable

data X where X :: (Eq a, Typeable a) => a -> X

instance Eq X where 
    X x == X y = Just x == cast y
```